# tmux online command reference

Tags: tmux

Does tmux have an online (built-in) command reference? I'm looking for something like vim's `:help diffput` for example.

I realize the man page exists. It's just imperfect for looking up a specific command. Say I want to see the documentation for `refresh-client`. Currently, I would do `man tmux` then `/refresh-client` and `n` until I found what looked right (the first instance is not the reference, it's some usage). I could do `/^     refresh-client` since references seem to match that pattern. But this all seems fiddly and too much work.

Comment: Nope. The closest you'll get is either `Prefix-?` for the keybinds or a hack like `bind-key T neww -n "Tmux manual" "exec man tmux"`...

Answer (score 2):

`:list-keys` - list currently recognized keys, and the commands they're bound to.

`:list-commands` - lists available commands

These might get you going.

Comment: Thanks. :list-commands is *close*. Still have to search afterwards. But it just shows the arguments :(